# Flutter: Running integration tests breaks unit tests

Tags: flutter, android-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing, flutter-test

Recently, I ran into an issue at work. To summarize it, I am currently working on writing test cases for an internal Flutter project. This had been working fine for a while, but after my summer vacation, it started breaking. It took me a while to figure out what roughly was going on, but I hen discovered that running integration tests generated a file named `generated_main.dart` under `.dart_tool/flutter_build/`. This was working just fine when using integration tests, however, it caused unit tests to fail due to not even loading.

I managed to identify the relevant line of code in the generated file as line eight: `import 'file:///tmp/flutter_tools.WJSDQT/flutter_test_listener.YHXZLS/listener.dart' as entrypoint;`. The capitalized strings of random characters are indeed random, apparently referring to a temporary path that only exists for the unit test's duration. Unit tests throw (even though not always reliably): `.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '/tmp/flutter_tools.WJSDQT/flutter_test_listener.YHXZLS/listener.dart': No such file or directory`.

Surprisingly, there seem to be no issues when deleting the generated file. I have now added a print statement to the integration tests that tells whoever ran them that they need to delete the generated file. But this is obviously not a good solution long-term. Is there a way to disable this behavior so that testing does not become unnecessarily more complicated?

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Flutter 2.5.0-5.1.pre on channel beta, using Android Studio 2020.3.1. I am not currently able to test for this behavior on other platforms. The program needs to run on Linux. The test package version is 1.17.10, the newest one compatible with other dependencies.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. After run integration test
and `listener.dart: No such file or directory` problem was started.

(flutter/packages: `dart run script/tool/bin/flutter_plugin_tools.dart native-test --ios --packages camera_avfoundation`)

But this was problem on previously builded `Runner.xc*` stuff - can't build `Runner` in XCode, can't test `RunnerTest` and e.t.c.

**Solved** by rebuilding `flutter build ios` (or run app's `main` from IDE).